# How to ignore complete folders for lint checking with gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, lint

I have an Android project that includes generated code. This code has some lint violations in it that I don't want to show up in the lint reports because we won't fix this code problems manually.

Is it somehow possible to exclude folders in the lint check?

Comment: See the [Lint docs](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings) for suppressing warnings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add to your project 'lint.xml' file with content as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <ignore path="build" />
</lint>
```

for example to ignore build path of that project.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as of the latest version of lint. I placed the lint.xml in the root of my project (where the gradlew binary typically goes) and also added `app/build` to the ignore path. Am I missing something?

Comment: see @Idolon's post below

Answer (score 27):

The correct way to do this is to add the following block to your app's `lint.xml` (this file is by default placed at the root of your app module):

```
<issue id="all">
    <ignore path="build" />
</issue>
```

This will instruct Lint to ignore *all* issues for the specified folder. If there is no `lint.xml` in your app module folder, create one with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="all">
        <ignore path="build" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

Comment: It worked well for lint <= 3.1, but for 3.2 it doesn't work. `lint` complains with `Error: Unknown issue id "all", found in ..../app/lint.xml [LintError]`

Comment: Exactly what @AlexanderSkvortsov said, anyone knows how to make it work with `all`?

Comment: @AlexanderSkvortsov this is a bug introduced in 3.2.0 by this [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/32969ce85a9115c66101e0e382431becc78c6e52%5E%21/lint/cli/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/LintCliClient.java). Please star the related Android issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116677290

Comment: This should work again in AS 3.3 and 3.4: `Fixed by Change-Id: Ibe1154541bf4e1fce821030e10753bef28046790 for 3.4 and cherrypick to 3.3 in progress.` https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116677290#comment4

Answer (score 6):

I had to specify the `issue` `id` as well as the ignored path. The `ignore` path alone didn't work.
Example with http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks lint check:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="MissingTranslation">
        <ignore path="build"/>
    </issue>
</lint>
```

You can find the issue id list [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks).
Your `lint.xml` is placed in your project directory.

Example:

```
./app/lint.xml
```